F# dynamically generated nested collection function signature cannot be unified
List.collect (fun l ->
        List.collect (fun ll ->
            List.collect (fun lll ->
                List.collect id lll
            ) ll
        ) l
    )  [
    [[[[[1;3]]]]]
    [[[[[2;4]]]]]
]


List.collect (fun ll ->
            List.collect (fun lll ->
                List.collect id lll
            ) ll
        ) [
    [[[[1;3]]]]
    [[[[2;4]]]]
]

I want to have something to dynamically generate the nested function to accecpt different input type signature list like int list list list list list or int list list list list list list to get int list list
But when trying to compose a functioin like this
let rec llf i ll : 'T list = 
    let rec f n =
        if n = 1 then
            fun l -> 
                List.collect id l
        else
            fun ln ->
                List.collect (llf (n - 1)) ln
    f i ll

It says
error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    ''T list list'    
but given a
    ''T list'    
The types ''T' and ''T list' cannot be unified.

How could I fix my code?

What you want to do can't be done in F# because of the static type system (or perhaps I haven't understood your problem). A function that accepts an int list list list list list is different from a function that accepts a 'int list list list list list list. There might be a way out with seq and reflection, but I'd suggest changing your approach instead if you can.

The challenge posed by type unification may be overcome with a discriminated union. Here, the union case A carries values, whose type is int list, and B marks the levels of nesting for removal, resulting in int list list in the examples below.
type 'a AB =
| A of 'a
| B of 'a AB list

let rec foo xs = [
    match xs with
    | A y -> yield y
    | B ys-> for y in ys do yield! foo y ]

A[1; 2] |> foo
B[A[1; 2]] |> foo
B[B[A[1; 2]]] |> foo
// val it : int list list = [[1; 2]]

B[A[1; 3]; A[2; 4]] |> foo
B[B[A[1; 3]; A[2; 4]]] |> foo
B[B[B[A[1; 3]]; B[A[2; 4]]]] |> foo
B[B[B[B[A[1; 3]]]; B[B[A[2; 4]]]]] |> foo
B[B[B[B[B[A[1; 3]]]]; B[B[B[A[2; 4]]]]]] |> foo
// val it : int list list = [[1; 3]; [2; 4]]


I may have found a solution to your problem, but I don't think it's very elegant/efficient, and if you have the opportunity, I suggest you change the way you do things (depending on your context, which we don't know).
Anyway, to begin with, as indicated in the comment to your question, F# is statically typed and doesn't allow first-order polymorphism, even less so when the implementations require an indeterminate number of cases (according to your question, you want a function to return an 'a list list no matter how many nested lists there are).
The approach to follow is therefore based on reflection, and on sequences in F#, which are practical for this style of use.
First, we define the following function:
let rec flattenSeq (input: seq<obj>) : seq<obj> =
    seq {
        for item in input do
            match item with
            | :? seq<obj> as subSeq -> yield! flattenSeq subSeq
            | _ -> yield item
    }

this function will take a sequence of objects (of indeterminate types) and recursively process each object that is detected as being a sequence (via the :? "operator"), the others are left in the sequence being processed.
To use this function, you'll need to box your nested lists (so as to convert them into obj). For example,
let example1 = [
    box [[[[1; 3]]]]
    box [[[[2; 4]]]]
]

let example2 = [
    box [[[[[1; 3]]]]]
    box [[[[[2; 4]]]]]
]

then,
let result1 = flattenSeq example1 |> Seq.toList
let result1 = flattenSeq example2 |> Seq.toList

and you have the expected result because the "unboxing" is done in the flattenSeq function (note that the conversion to a list is not necessary at the end, but you seem to work on list).
With this implementation, you have the constraint of providing boxed lists as illustrated (otherwise the F# type system will come back to bite you).
It's up to you to adapt the code to your needs, but you'll always have the constraint of the F# type system, so you won't be able to write a function more general than that, I think.
